# How to specify the architecture of deep neural network in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am newbie in Tensorflow

Actually, I am testing some example in Tensorflow web-site, and I start to understand some features of the framwork, but what I don't understand is how I can design my architecture, I mean number of layers, type of Layer "conv, pool...", and if it is necessery to do that, because there are many predifined architectures like AmexNet,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend working through their hands on tutorial, depending on if you have previous ML experience (https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) or not (https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners). The questions you are asking are answered in there.

The question on using predefined architectures or self defined depends on your use case. If you want to do something easy like classifying if there is only a car in the scene or not a more shallow architecture might work better, because it is faster and a more deep one is overkill. However most architectures are similar to the ones already defined in literature.

Another question that arises naturally, while talking about pre defined architecture is about transfer learning / fine tuning. Often pre defined architectures are already learned on some big dataset (mostly ImageNet) and already perform really well out of the box for many tasks. With little training data it makes a lot of sense to use this. With lots of training data it can hinder your progress though.